# Select only top outer wall

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

Beginner in Blender, Please pardon if it's a noob question, But I tried several methods to achieve this.

I have a 3d Case I want to increase the height of the walls, without changing anything (holes, etc.) However not able to find a suitable way to do it

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The faces are also on the same plane, so you could select one of them and use Select Similar menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and choose Coplanar. You might need to adjust the Threshold in the Adjust Last Operation menu.

[image]

Comment: Although my design is a bit complex however your answers help, adding and removing a few vertexes manually, I wonder if we can reduce some vertex noise, without changing anything. It will help to better select what I want.

Comment: The selection functions work on models of any complexity. Maybe there are some issues with the model. Try recalculating normals(shift+n with all selected in edit mode) and merging vertices by distance to remove double vertices (m -> b with all selected in edit mode and adjust merge distance to very small).

Answer (score 2):

1. With your object selected, go in Edit Mode with <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
2. Set your view to the side using <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>
3. Toggle ON the X-Ray using <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or clicking this button:
   [image: xray]
4. Make sure you are in Face Selection mode:
   [image: face selection]
5. Make sure you have nothing selected by pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
6. Drag a rectangle selection over the top faces of your mesh, try to make the rectangle barely go over the top faces
   [image: select]
7. Since your faces are all flat, you should be able to move them in one direction by pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z Z</kbd>, moving your cursor, and <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to validate the move.